# How to setup Privileged Identity Management for Cosmos DB Built-in Data Reader Role

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, rbac

I want to setup Privileged Identity Management for Cosmos DB Built-in Data Reader Role. But this **Cosmos DB Built-in Data Reader Role** is not present in the role assignment.

I am able to assign this role to user/groups using powershell script. But this Role is not visible in IAM of the cosmos db resource.

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos DB uses similar models like Azure RBAC but it is not Azure RBAC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#concepts.

> The Azure Cosmos DB data plane RBAC is built on concepts that are commonly found in other RBAC systems like Azure RBAC

So the concepts are the same, but those role definitions and assignments are not visible to Azure RBAC.
And so they won't be visible in PIM either until they add Cosmos DB RBAC support :\